# Converting strings to numpy arrays to run a for loop on dataframe linear regression

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, linear-regression

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import os
os.chdir(r'path')
df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
print(df)
def process_date(date_str):
  # the date format is month-day-year
  d = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m-%d-%Y')
  return d.timestamp()

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(process_date)
df.head()
for (columnName, columnData) in df.iteritems():
    cn = columnName
    cd = columnData
    print('Column Name : ', columnName)
    print('Column Contents : ', columnData.values)
X = np.array(cn).reshape(-1,1)
y = cd.to_numpy()
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)
```

ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'

Here is my dataset
[image]

Comment: Am I missing something or have you never actually assigned the variables `columnData` and `columnName`

Comment: You were right, I hadn't thanks for pointing that out, still getting same ValueError: Unable to convert array of bytes/strings into decimal numbers with dtype='numeric'

Comment: my dataframe is just one column of dates the other of sales for each column

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the dataframe as a dummy in the code above? That would help alot.

Comment: Hey @nhaus I added a picture of a sample of my dataset

Comment: At a high level, I just want to loop through the columns and dates and create a linear regression for each column.